# Different colored dice placed in urns.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

You roll $6$ die, $2$ red dice, $2$ blue dice and $2$ green dice. Any  number rolled between $1-2$ is placed in Urn 1, any number rolled between $3-4$ goes into Urn $2$, and any number rolled between 5-6 goes into Urn $3$.

a) What is the probability that each 2 of the same colored die end up in the same urn (ie. you cant have the 2 red and the 2 blue dice in the same urn)?

b) What is the probability that exactly 2 die end up in each urn (color doesn't matter for this part)?

For part a), I just thought of it like this... first die of any color can be placed anywhere and the die of the same color has a 1/3 chance of being placed with it. The second color die can be placed in 2 of the remaining urns (2/3) and the other same colored die needs to be placed in that urn as well (1/3), the final colored die need to be placed in the last remaining urn so (1/3) and the second die of that color needs to be placed in that urn as well (1/3). So i got $(3/3)*(1/3)*(2/3)*(1/3)*(1/3)*(1/3)=6/729$

For part b, i got the probability that exactly two die end up in each urn to be 1/3 since the die color doesnt matter here.

Do these answer make sense? If they are incorrect where did i go wrong?

Comment: What does "all three urns must be filled" mean if you roll the dice and they all show $5$ or $6$?

Comment: Any dice rolled that is a 1 or 2 goes into Urn 1, any dice rolled that is a 3 or 4 goes into Urn 2, any dice rolled that is a 5 or 6 goes into Urn 3. I guess i worded that wrong. All i meant is what is the probability that the two red dice end up in a urn together, the two blue dice end up in a urn together and the two green dice end up in an urn together, but these cannot be the same urns. Ie. if two red and 2 blue dice are placed into urn 1 and urn 2 has 2 green dice, this does not satisfy the conditions.

Comment: The analysis in a) looks good. For b) I get  $90/729$.

Comment: I think the wording you want is "each urn ends up containing two dice of the same color" or "the two dice of each color end up in the same urn but but each urn has exactly one pair of dice" or such.  Your current wording implies 4 or 6 dice could be in the same urn and your "i.e." rewrites by adding a condition, rather than clarifyig.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) seems to be correct to me.

b) Your reasoning isn't clear. Ignore the color of the dice and just label them 1 through six. The first die can be paired to any of five other die.  The third die can be paired with any of the three other die and the fifth and sixth die must be paired.  This is 15 possible pairings.  The first pair can go in any of the three urns, the second in any of the 2, and the last in the third.  There are 6 ways times the fifteen pairings is 90 possible ways this can happen.  There are $3^6 = 729$ total possible outcomes.   So the probability  90/729 or 10/81.

I think.